# Laravel passport & Vue login

Tags: laravel, authentication, vue.js, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I've made login function in laravel with passport api and I'm getting status 200, **the issue is** that i don't know how to login the user and redirect to homepage after this successful request **(I'm using vuejs component)**.

## Code

`controller`

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = [
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password
        ];

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            // $token = auth()->user()->createToken('AppName')->accessToken;
            // $success['token'] =  $token;
            // $success['name'] =  auth()->user()->name;
            // $success['id'] =  auth()->user()->id;
          $user = Auth::user();
            $success['token'] = $user->createToken('AppName')->accessToken;
            $success['user'] = $user;
            return response()->json(['success'=>$success], 200);
        } else {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'UnAuthorised'], 401);
        }
    }
```

`component script`

```
<script>
    import {login} from '../../helpers/Auth';

    export default {
        name: "login",
        data() {
            return {
                form: {
                    email: '',
                    password: ''
                },
                error: null
            };
        },
        methods: {
            authenticate() {
                this.$store.dispatch('login');

                axios.post('/api/auth/login', this.form)
                .then((response) => {
                    setAuthorization(response.data.access_token);
                    res(response.data);
                })
                .catch((err) =>{
                    rej("Wrong email or password");
                })

            }
        },
        computed: {
            authError() {
                return this.$store.getters.authError;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

`Auth.js (imported in script above)`

```
import { setAuthorization } from "./general";

export function login(credentials) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        axios.post('/api/auth/login', credentials)
            .then((response) => {
                setAuthorization(response.data.access_token);
                res(response.data);
            })
            .catch((err) =>{
                rej("Wrong email or password");
            })
    })
}
```

`general.js (imported in script above)`

```
export function setAuthorization(token) {
    axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`
}
```

## Question

1. How can I login my user after successful request?

...........................................................................................................................................................

Comment: if token is correct then user will be authorized on the server. Also you need to get user from the server if you have a token.

Comment: I don't really understand what your problem is. If you get a 200 status code back, you also get a token back. That token means that the user is logged in. You can make requests to endpoints that require the user to be logged in with that token. You are already logged in. If you are making a SPA then `this.$router.push('/')` is enough to go to the homepage. You probably want to keep your login state in a `vuex` store.

Comment: @Sumurai8 that's exactly what I'm trying to do, i am getting status 200 and token all i need is to bring server login in front-end and so user can avoid of seeing login page also can have access to their profile page etc. **I don't know how to bring that server login into front end** can you help with that?

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько i do have token, the issue is I don't know how to use that token in front end so user knows is login and can have access to the parts that requires authentication

Comment: @mafortis you can get a user on every page when you have a token. Token must be stored in localeStorage or Cookie. If you have received a user, then consider that the user is authorized, you can use his data. Or do you not know how to store  token and user? There are many guides on Internet.

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько thanks for responding, unfortunately all the articles i found by google are copy paste and just talking about how to install passport and maximum how to make login page, none of them talk about how to use that data after the login. Ps: I'll find the solution thanks for your time.

Answer (score 7):

Say that you have defined a vuex auth module with a login action
that accepts a credentials object.

If success it receives a response that contains the access_token our API granted to the user.

We store/commit the token and also update axios settings to use that token on each of the following requests we make.

```
import axios from 'axios';

const state = {
    accessToken: null,
};

const mutations = {
    setAccessToken: (state, value) => {
        state.accessToken = value;
    },
};

const getters = {
    isAuthenticated: (state) => {
        return state.accessToken !== null;
    },
};

const actions = {
    /**
     * Login a user
     * 
     * @param context {Object} 
     * @param credentials {Object} User credentials
     * @param credentials.email {string} User email
     * @param credentials.password {string} User password
     */
    login(context, credentials) {
        return axios.post('/api/login', credentials)
            .then((response) => {
                // retrieve access token
                const { access_token: accessToken } = response.data;

                // commit it
                context.commit('setAccessToken', accessToken);

                return Promise.resolve();
            })
            .catch((error) => Promise.reject(error.response));
    },
};
```

Before every request to our API we need to send the token we received and store on our auth module therefore we define a global axios request interceptor on our main.js

```
import store from '@/store';

...

axios.interceptors.request.use(
    (requestConfig) => {
        if (store.getters['auth/isAuthenticated']) {
            requestConfig.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${store.state.auth.accessToken}`;
        }
        return requestConfig;
    },
    (requestError) => Promise.reject(requestError),
);

...
```

We then define our login component which on a success login redirects us to the dashboard page

```
<template>
    <div>
        ...
        <form @submit.prevent="submit">
            ...
            <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
        ...
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions } from 'vuex';

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            credentials: {
                email: '',
                password: '',
            },
        };
    },
    methods: {
        ...mapActions('auth', [
            'login',
        ]),
        submit() {
            this.login({ ...this.credentials })
                .then(() => {
                    this.$router.replace('/dashboard');
                })
                .catch((errors) => {
                    // Handle Errors
                });
        },
    },
}
```

Finally we define our routes and their guards

```
import store from '@/store'

export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'landing',
            component: Landing,
            // User MUST NOT BE authenticated
            beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
                const isAuthenticated = store.getters['auth/isAuthenticated'];

                if (isAuthenticated) {
                    return next({
                        name: 'dashboard',
                    });
                }

                return next();
            },
        },
        {
            path: '/login',
            name: 'login',
            component: Login,
            // User MUST NOT BE authenticated
            beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
                const isAuthenticated = store.getters['auth/isAuthenticated'];

                if (isAuthenticated) {
                    return next({
                        name: 'dashboard',
                    });
                }

                return next();
            },
        },
        {
            path: '/dashboard',
            name: 'dashboard',
            component: Dashboard,
            // User MUST BE authenticated
            beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
                const isAuthenticated = store.getters['auth/isAuthenticated'];

                if (!isAuthenticated) {
                    return next({
                        name: 'login',
                    });
                }

                return next();
            },
        },
        { path: '*', redirect: '/' },
    ],
});
```

Now only users with an access token can have access to dashboard route and any child routes you may define in the future. (No further check is necessary as any child of this route will execute that guard).

If someone attempts to access dashboard route without an access token will be redirected to login page

If someone attempts to access landing or login page with an access token will be redirected back to dashboard.

**Now what happens if on any of our future API requests our token is invalid?**

we add a global axios response interceptor on our main.js and whenever we receive a 401 unathorized response we clear our current token and redirect to login page

```
import store from '@/store';

...

axios.interceptors.response.use(
    response => response,
    (error) => {

        if (error.response.status === 401) {
            // Clear token and redirect
            store.commit('auth/setAccessToken', null);
            window.location.replace(`${window.location.origin}/login`);
        }

        return Promise.reject(error);
    },
);

...
```

### Final Words

I believe that all of the above steps are enough to help you have a better understanding on how to use the access token. Of course you should also store the token on browsers localStorage so that the user doesnot have to login whenever experiences a page refresh and token gets clear from memory. And at least refactor router beforeEnter functions by moving them to a separate file to avoid repetition.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for this complete answer. I'll test it and get back to you.